# Vector.size() in Java

Tags: java, vector

How does `Vector.size()` work exactly, is it returning something that is aleready known like `Array.length` or it makes calculations every time?

My point is.. is it better to have another variable to store a vector's size when I need to use it in a loop for example :

```
int vectorLength = myVector.size();
for (int i = 0; i < vectorLength; i++) {
//...
}
```

Or I can use directly `Vector.size()`  ?  Which is better in terms of memory and cpu time used?

Comment: You can simply take a look at the source code of ``java.util.Vector`` and find out!

Comment: `Vector.size()` is a synchronized method. It has lock/unlock overhead.

Comment: @Poyr23 You may accept 1 solution which helps you best.

Comment: Unless you need the synchronized behavior of [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), don't use it. It got replaced in Java 1.2 back in 1998. See javadoc: *"If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is **recommended** to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`."* If you do need synchronization, I'd recommend using `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())` instead, i.e. don't use `Vector`, ever.

Comment: @Andreas  ok, thanks for the tip, I will keep that in mind, I was wondering why nobody uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the actual codes how they implements it:

```
  308       * @return  the number of components in this vector
  309       */
  310       public synchronized int size() {
  311           return elementCount;
  312       }
```

The link is here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Vector.java.html

It basically just get the int value like a getter.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not make a difference. Vector.size() simply returns an int. So its the same O(1) operation when you call an int that holds the size

Comment: So it's like a simple mutator? (getters, and setters)

Comment: exactly its a simple getter

Comment: I prefer store size in variable and then check it in for loops. Also I think read variable is faster than get the value from method call.